# sublime sftp - how to edit and save files with sudo privilages

Tags: ssh, sublimetext3, sftp, sudo, sublime-text-plugin

Many servers have root login disabled and there are many files on server you can only edit and save with root or sudo privileges,

when you create a sftp server on Sublime ,it asks about login credentials , and you can enter only non-root user details as root login(ssh to root)  is disabled.
but you cannot edit particular files without sudo , as it gives permission denied if you try ..

so is there any way to save files via sudo , or login as root directly after initial login(not recommended i know but once logged in as root will give permission to  save any file).

any solution is welcomed but if possible a simpler solution without using too many extra plug-ins or multiple configuration files are preferred.

sublime: v3, local/server to sftp to: Ubuntu

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: @Parzival , currently , as far as i have seen , there is no direct solution through sublime,
an alternative is to change the owner of the files you want to access/edit via sublime to the user you are using in sublime ,  `chown sublim-access-user filename`
or to give those files open permissions ,  `chmod 777 file_name /folder name`